# Identify this sword!

Tags: identification, sword

Anyone know anything about the markings on this sword?

This is a set of photos from a student I work with. Her grandfather gave it to her and said that his grandfather gave it to him. Unfortunately grandfather is no longer with us so we can't ask him anything about it.

[image: Sword full view]

[image: Sword holder]

[image: Sword Markings]

[image: Sword Leather]

[image: Sword Hilt]

[image: Sword Hilt]

Comment: Do we perhaps at least know where these various grandfathers are from?

Comment: Wow, that's incredible. Looks 15th or 16th century South Russia to me, maybe even Ottoman or Caucasian, but that is just a sheer guess. Could be very valuable.

Comment: If you could provide a closeup of the pommel that would be useful.

Comment: I will guess 18th century Ottoman, but we really need an expert to figure it out for sure. If this guess is right, it might be worth $200 to $300.

Comment: @TylerDurden - How do you figure? Everything I've been able to dig up about Ottoman swords shows them curved. Same for Russian swords after roughly the 14th century.

Comment: @T.E.D. The museum swords you see are officer swords. This is a much more ordinary infantry sword. The metallurgy is very good and the thin blade spells Damascus. The tooling looks Ottoman to me.

Comment: The takouba guess below looks pretty good. I have sent the photos to a couple of experts. Hopefully one of them will get back to me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**A tuareg takooba sword, maybe**

Scabbard and half-moon markings on the blade are reasonably similar to a **[tuareg takooba sword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takoba)** shown on [antiqueswordsonline](http://www.antiqueswordsonline.com/new-19th20th-century-north-african-kaskara-sword-new/). See images below: *note that the half-moon markings appear at the same place as on the sword above, where the two outer fullers (grooves) end*.

From a general description:

> "The typical blade tapers, especially distally, to a rounded point. The edges may be irregular from repeated sharpening, especially toward the tip. The method of sharpening leaves a roughly striated appearance on the flats of the blades adjacent to the edges [...]
>   the usual narrow central fullers (grooves) running parallel to the length of the blade from the hilt often appear to be ground, having striations, and sometimes do not show the degree of pitting and irregularities otherwise characterizing the rest of the surface. The typical blade will have three such fullers, the central being longer than those on either side."  ([Takouba
>   ~ Swords of the Saharan Tuareg](http://www.vikingsword.com/ethsword/takouba.html)  - This site also has more images and of various types of takoobas and further references)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first picture showing the same three blade lines and two squiggles in a semicircle looks pretty darn definitive to me.

Comment: From the link, apparently Tuareg warriors have an aversion to touching metal, which explains why not only the hilt but the guard as well appear to be wrapped in leather.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted the photos to a dealer and he said the sword is, as Mario Elocio said, of North African make. He said it was made sometime between 1900-1950 and would be worth $100 to $200 on eBay.